# Height of page not resizing depending on amount of content in div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, resize

I need my website (https://newmedia.leeds.ac.uk/ug10/cs10enw/portfolio/index.html#one) to resize each page window depending on the height of .content. The HTML is all in one file with a page slider effect. Each page has a class .page and an ID (#page-one, #page-two, etc). The .page is being given a width and height from what I can only assume is in JS but cannot find it anywhere! This is setting each page to the same height, which means some content is being cut off at a certain point, and others have too much white space at the bottom.

I desperately need help, please!

Here is the JS I think has something to do with it:

```
    // Resize pages on window resize
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    dx = $(window).width();
    dy = $(window).height();
    $resize.css({
        width: dx - 500,
        height: dy + 580
        //width: dx - 500,
        //height: 3000
    });
    if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(scrollToPage, 900);
});
```

But not sure if it is that or not.

Comment: Does the element .content contain any floated elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).resize(respondToResize);

function respondToResize() {
    options.width = jQuery("body").width();
    options.height = jQuery("body").height();
    //Optionally all other functions below to redraw other content (texts, images, etc.)

}

//Initial call 
respondToResize();
```